# HTML and CSS trouble with line, next line clings to previous one

Tags: html, css

I have trouble with HTML. Please take a look at the screenshot. When I have too long text then next line start from this one item, because it clings to this.

[attached screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZZot.png)

How I can resolve it?

Comment: please also post your code and show us what you've tried so far

Comment: Without knowing the html structure and the CSS properties, how are we supposed to help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

most probably you've used `float: left` for `li`. either you can use `flex` or `inline-block` to fix this issue.

Comment: I would agree with using `inline-block` as `flex` isn't as well supported.

Comment: depends on the requirement. `flex` is supported in all the modern browsers. if the requirement isn't for IE10 and below, it's better to use `flex`

Comment: If you want to try out flex box you should take a look here: [A Complete Guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: @ViktorLeschuk for future reference, please update your question and add HTML and CSS codes as well so others can understand the problem and solution. also don't forget to accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

i should make a adaptive way, use j-query and make a same height on most of your boxes. this way it stay's clean, design technical.

an example: http://brm.io/jquery-match-height/

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to create pin interest type layout.

You can use : http://masonry.desandro.com/